# Reference request for some determinants of binomial coefficients

Tags: co.combinatorics, determinants, binomial-coefficients, catalan-numbers

Let $C_{n}=\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{n+1}$ be a Catalan number. I am interested in books or papers where the following identities occur:
$$\det\left(\binom{i+j+1}{i-j+1}\right)_{0 \leq i,j\leq {n-1}}=C_{n}$$
and
$$\det\left(\binom{i+j+2}{i-j+1}\right)_{0 \leq i,j\leq {n-1}}=C_{n+1}$$
I have already posted a more general question in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2928770/reference-request-for-some-determinants-of-binomial-coefficients, but did not get an answer.

Comment: Let $\, a_{n,k} := \det (A_{n,k}) \,$ where
 $\, A_{n,k} := \{{i+j+k-1 \choose i-j+1}\}_{1\le i,j\le n}.\,$
Then $\, a_{n,k} = (k+1) { 2n+k \choose n }/(n+k+1). \,$
See [OEIS sequence A054445](http://oeis.org/A054445).

Comment: Just for the record and (perhaps) some insight: $\det\left(\binom{i+j+k}{i-j+1}\right)=C_n*C_n*\cdots *C_n$, a (discrete) convolution of $k$ Catalans.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a paper
  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0196885801907328
Advances in Applied Mathematics
Volume 27, Issues 2–3, August 2001, Pages 225-230.

Comment: Thank you. I know your paper and I have in fact used the Condensation Method to compute the more general determinant $\det\left(\binom{i+j+x+k-2}{i-j+k}\right)_{0 \leq i,j\leq {n-1}}.$
But the two special cases are so simple that I suppose that these must be old results and I want to know who has found them first.